# Цикл Button.Enabled для нескольких значений ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Столкнулся с проблемой: мне нужно чтобы занятые места (созданные в виде кнопок), нельзя было выбрать. То есть переключить их значение Enabled в false. Проблема в том, что выставив 1 кнопку цикл завершается. Каким образом я могу реализовать блокировку этих кнопок или как можно заставить исправно работать цикл?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    string num_p = "";
    string command_sql = "SELECT TOP " + i + " number_place FROM bookings WHERE id_connection_a = @idcon AND date_buy = @date";
    string connectionString1 = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TS_DB"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString1);
    SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(command_sql, con1);
    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idcon", Session["id_selected_connection"].ToString().Trim());
    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", Session["id_selected_date"].ToString().Trim());
    con1.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command1.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            num_p = reader["number_place"].ToString();
        }
    }
    con1.Close();

    switch (num_p)
    {
        case "1":
            ButtonPlac1.Enabled = false;
            break;
        case "2":
            ButtonPlac2.Enabled = false;
            break;
}};
```

Привёл только часть кода. В общем кнопок более сорока. 10 в цикле показательна, её число определяется запросом к БД немного ранее.

[image: вид панели с кнопками]

Comment: Что то вы вообще странное делаете. Вам не надо в цикле считывать значения их базы по одному, вам надо 1 раз в базу обратиться и получить все занятые места.

Comment: Я уже понял, почему всё не работало и исправил. Но спасибо за ваше уточнение, попробую и так тоже.